# Ajax call returning current page full page HTML instead of the expected data

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax call but the result is my current page full HTML code. I have removed all the codes inside the php file except for that one line (below) but the error still persists, Please i need help here. which part of the ajax call is calling the current page html?
Here is my PHP code,

```
<?php
    echo "success";
?>
```

**Ajax call**

```
//TRANSFER MODULE AJAX CALL
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#transfer_Form').submit(function(){
        let datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'transfer.php',
            data: datatopost,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result){

                if(result == 'success'){
                    $('#transfer_msg'). html(result);
                }else{
                    $('#transfer_msg'). html('Nothing come out');
                }

            },
            error: function(){
                $('#transfer_msg'). html("Error transfer");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: How does your form look like in html? Try changing .submit with .on("submit", function(e){});

Comment: It was ```.on("submit", function(e){});``` before i change it to submit

Comment: Can you post the html part where you define your form?